# Add a column at the end of a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, insert, append

This question has been asked many many times. Still I could not figure out the answer. SORRY.
Here I give a minimal example:

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[1.,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
print(A)
x,y=A.shape
B=np.full(x,-1.0)
print(B)
#np.concatenate((A,B),1)
np.hstack((A,B))
```

I wanted an array like:

```
C=np.array([[1.,2,3,-1.],[4,5,6,-1.0],[7,8,9,-1.0],[10,11,12,-1.0]])
print(C)
>>>>
[[ 1.  2.  3. -1.]
 [ 4.  5.  6. -1.]
 [ 7.  8.  9. -1.]
 [10. 11. 12. -1.]]
```

I tried everything (`append, hstack, concatenate, insert`) but am getting this dimension mismatch error all the time. Please help.

Comment: Did you try to understand and correct the dimension mismatch?  Sounds like you just tried a different function.  That's not how you learn.

Comment: May I ask you a different question? Sometimes, `numpy.array` gives (at least while printed) comma separated array (like after the operations mentioned below) and sometimes not (like my `A` array in the question). Is there a significant difference or they just behave similarly?

Comment: The `print(X)` of a numpy array omits the commas. The `repr` display includes them (along with `np.array`.  The intent is to distinguish them in subtle ways from lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [14]: A=np.array([[1.,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
    ...: print(A)
    ...: x,y=A.shape
    ...: B=np.full(x,-1.0)
    ...: print(B)
[[ 1.  2.  3.]
 [ 4.  5.  6.]
 [ 7.  8.  9.]
 [10. 11. 12.]]
[-1. -1. -1. -1.]
In [15]: A.shape
Out[15]: (4, 3)
In [16]: B.shape
Out[16]: (4,)
```

Your dimensions error:

```
In [17]: np.concatenate((A,B), 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-17-8dc80544006c>", line 1, in <module>
    np.concatenate((A,B), 1)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in concatenate
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)
```

The problem should be obvious.  One array is (4,3), the other (4,), 2d and 1d.

We can easily add a dimension to `B` (`B.reshape(4,1)` will also work):

```
In [18]: B[:,None].shape
Out[18]: (4, 1)
In [19]: np.concatenate((A,B[:,None]), 1)
Out[19]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3., -1.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6., -1.],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9., -1.],
       [10., 11., 12., -1.]])
```

Trying the other functions doesn't help. It's apparent from the `hstack` error that is just passes the job on to `concatenate`:

```
In [20]: np.hstack((A,B))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-20-56593299da4e>", line 1, in <module>
    np.hstack((A,B))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in hstack
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 346, in hstack
    return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 1)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in concatenate
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)
```

`np.append` does as well.

`column_stack` uses `concatenate` as well, but adjusts the arrays to be 2d:

```
In [22]: np.column_stack((A,B))
Out[22]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3., -1.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6., -1.],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9., -1.],
       [10., 11., 12., -1.]])
```

Pay attention to the error messages, and try to learn from them.  Your future programming self will thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Because B is 1-D matrix, while A is 2-D matrix.
Change B to `np.array([[-1.] for _ in range(x)])`, then `np.hstack((A,B))` can work.

```py
>>> B=np.array([[-1.] for _ in range(x)])
        
>>> B
        
array([[-1.],
       [-1.],
       [-1.],
       [-1.]])
>>> np.hstack((A,B))
        
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3., -1.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6., -1.],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9., -1.],
       [10., 11., 12., -1.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.column_stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html):

```
>>> A=np.array([[1.,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
>>> x,y = A.shape
>>> B = np.full(x,-1.0)
>>> np.column_stack((A,B))
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3., -1.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6., -1.],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9., -1.],
       [10., 11., 12., -1.]])
```

You can also try this approach:

```
>>> B = np.full((x,y+1),-1)
>>> B[:,:-1] = A
>>> B
array([[ 1,  2,  3, -1],
       [ 4,  5,  6, -1],
       [ 7,  8,  9, -1],
       [10, 11, 12, -1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try instead [`numpy.insert()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([
    [1., 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]
])
# print(A)
A = np.insert(A, 3, values=[-1] * 4, axis=1)
print(A)
```

Or, more generally, using the shape:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([
    [1., 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]
])
# print(A)
x, y = A.shape
A = np.insert(A, y, values=[-1] * x, axis=1)
print(A)
```

In both cases, you should get:

```
[[ 1.  2.  3. -1.]
 [ 4.  5.  6. -1.]
 [ 7.  8.  9. -1.]
 [10. 11. 12. -1.]]
```